# Load bitmap into array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, image, dictionary, bitmap

For a project I need to make a map in Java that a robot can navigate through. Preferably, I'd like to store the map in a 2D-array, but I don't know how to go from the 1 bit bitmap to an array in Java. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `ImageIO.read()` method to load your bitmap in a `BufferedImage` instance. Then, call `BufferedImage.getRGB(int x, int y)` to get the color value of a particuliar pixel of your map.

Comment: Hi, The grid i'm gonna use measures 800x600 so manually adding is not an option. I think Nicolas' answer is what I'm trying at the moment. However, I'm trying to read the DataBuffer banks, but it only gives me 6000 entries. Whereas there should be 480.000 entries,; the amount of pixels in the image. There is only 1 bank present, so I have no idea why I only get 6000 entries.

Comment: By reading the `DataBuffer` directly, you gonna have to deal with the low level format of your image. You better stick with `BufferImage.getRGB(int x, int y)` IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a 10 by 10 grid, then you would create an array such as

```
Image[][] grid = new Image[10][10];
```

Then

```
for (int x = 0; X < grid.length; X++) {
  for (int y = 0; y < grid[x].length; y++) {
     grid[x][y] = theImageForThisPosition;
  }
}
```

However, as you are storing 1 bit bitmaps, it would be much more efficient to store Color objects, rather than Image objects.